# Чат на node.js и socket.io на OpenServer

Tags: node.js, openserver, socket.io

пробую запустить простой чат на OpenServer
файл index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use(require('express').static(__dirname + '/public'));

const userList = new Set();
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('user connected');

    socket.emit('userList', Array.from(userList));
    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
    socket.on('news', function (nickName) {
        socket.nickName = nickName;
        userList.add(nickName);
        io.emit('news', nickName);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');

        io.emit('disconnect', socket.nickName);
        userList.delete(socket.nickName);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>node-chat</title>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/code.js"></script>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close " data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title center" id="myModalLabel">Enter nickname:</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body center" id="modalEdit">
                <div class="form-group center">
                    <strong>nickname:</strong>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control center" id="nickname" placeholder="at least 3 symbols">
                    <div class="alert alert-error center" id="alert-error">
                        Minimum nickname length must be 3 symbols!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="login">log In</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" id="btnExit"><i class="icon-off"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9 background">
            <div class="well well-small center">
                <i class="icon-comment"></i>Happy talking!
            </div>
            <ul id="messages">
            </ul>
            <form role="form" id="foother">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="span9" type="text" id="m" placeholder="Enter message" autocomplete="off">
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn span9 btn-info" id="btnSend">Send</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="span3" id="divContactList">
            <div class="well well-small center">
                <i class="icon-user"></i>Online:
            </div>
            <div id="сontactList">
                <ul class="list-group">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

В папку с проектом, через консоль установил npm express и socket.io

Запускаю командой из консоли `node index`
Ответ `listening on *:3000`

Пытаюсь написать в чат - без результатов, сообщение не выводится. Подскажите что делаю не так?

Comment: Зачем Вам Openserver?

Comment: Можно просто с локальной среды запустить? (с диска C скажем?)

Comment: Пробовал также из командной windows, ситуация аналогичная